# Array of concrete class not covariant with array of interface

Tags: d

I'm having a little problem in providing an abstract base layer for my `dataaccess.mysqlclient` module where I have defined a bunch of interfaces for minimum requirements and a bunch of classes that implement them.

Now the dmd compiler complains:

`Error: function dataaccess.mysqlclient.MySqlReader.columns of type @property MySqlColumnInfo[]() overrides but is not covariant with dataaccess.dbclient.IDbReader.columns of type @property IDbColumnInfo[]()
Exit code 1`

the relevant lines of code look like this:

IDbReader:

```
interface IDbReader
{
    @property IDbColumnInfo[] columns();
    // ... 
}
```

MySqlReader:

```
class MySqlReader : IDbReader
{
    private MySqlColumnInfo[] _columns;
    @property public MySqlColumnInfo[] columns() {return _columns;}
    // ... 
}
```

There are a few ways I could probably work around this compiler issue;

- Declare the concrete property to be of `IDbColumnInfo[]`
- wrap the array in a list class

And probably a couple more if i think about it a bit longer. None of those seem quite elegant though.

**Here come the big questions:**

- Am I overlooking something simple?
- Can arrays of implementations ever be covariant with arrays of interfaces?

Also I can't really imagine the reason for the compilers' complaint. There are more complex structures in my code that have been compiling just fine. So if somebody can explain why this won't work as is, That'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have run into the problem of [array covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Arrays).

Let's assume that your code compiled fine. Now, consider the following code:

```
class SomeOtherColumnInfo : IDbColumnInfo {}

IDbReader reader = new MySqlReader(...);
IDbColumnInfo[] columns = reader.columns;
columns[3] = new SomeOtherColumnInfo(); // OK
```

Since the array is mutable, we can overwrite its elements with instances of other `IDbColumnInfo`-derived classes. The problem with that is that we're also modifying the private `_columns` field of `MySqlReader`. So, now we have a `SomeOtherColumnInfo` instance as a member of the `MySqlColumnInfo[]` array. Thus, we've broken the type system without using casts or other unsafe code. Since the compiler is expected to stop us from doing that by accident, it will refuse to implicitly cast mutable arrays of classes to arrays of other classes, even if those classes are related.

Now, I think it would make sense for D to allow compilation if the returned array was not mutable (that is, const or immutable). However, the compiler doesn't like that either. I don't know if that's an omission, or if there's a reason unknown to me.

Comment: I figured  as much, but don't understand why that would pose a problem. Since, as far as I can see, `SomeOtherColumnInfo` would have to be a subclass of `MySqlColumnInfo` in this case. In other words; I don't understand how that breaks the type system.

Comment: @Kris Think about what would happen if you cast `MySqlReader[]` to `IDbReader[]` and then appended a `PosixReader` to it or replaced one its elements with a `PosixReader`. You would have just put a `PosixReader` in what is really an array of `MySqlReader[]`, which would definitely break the type system. In general, it makes no sense to cast a container of `DerivedClass` to a container of `BaseClass`, much as it might at first seem like it would.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: Yes I sort of see that but just can't really get my head around the idea that they both implement the same contract, so should fit in the same slots. If they wouldn't both be `Duck` the programmer wouldn't have tagged them that way right? As long as the  type system asserts `PosixReader` to be a subclass of `MySqlReader` in that scenario. Isn't `List<String>` a subclass of `List<Object>` in c#? (I believe it is but haven't checked) Problem seems to be solved by having `MySqlColumnInfoList : ArrayWrapper!(IDbColumnInfo)` here. Now I still have to do that for a few more cases.

Comment: Quoth the MSDN: "Because of array covariance, assignments to elements of reference type arrays include a run-time check that ensures that the value being assigned to the array element is actually of a permitted type." That's the only reason List<String> is allowed to be a subclass of List<Object> in C#.

Comment: The important thing to realize is that they _don't_ implement the same contract, because arrays have two operations - get  element, which does implement covariance (because they _return_ a supertype), and _set_ element (or append element), which, since it takes the new element as a parameter, requires **contravariance**. So whichever way you cast an array, you have to throw away half its contract. So you could, symmetrically, cast something like an Object[] to an Apple[\*], where T[\*] is a "blind array" or "contravariant array" that only supported assignment and appending, not lookup.